# Periodic job to find resource groups with tags corresponding to recently deleted users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, powershell-core

We have a tag policy in place such that each resource group has a `Tech-Owner-Email` and `Tech-Owner-Name` tag.

We want to be notified when people leaving the org have resource groups under their name.

What's a good way to find groups belonging to people who have recently left?

We will want this process to run periodically and to notify us with any results (email, teams, whatever works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph API has an endpoint that lists recently deleted users [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user

This can be polled via the Azure CLI to get the list of people, then `az cli` can also be used to get the list of tags from resource groups.

## The script

```
#!/usr/bin/pwsh
Write-Host "Fetching deleted users"
$deletedUsers = az rest `
--method "GET" `
--url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user" `
--headers "Content-Type=application/json" | ConvertFrom-Json

if ($deletedUsers.value.count -eq 0)
{
    Write-Warning "No deleted users found"
    return
}

Write-Host "Gathering subscriptions"
$subs = az account list | ConvertFrom-Json
$found=0
foreach ($sub in $subs)
{
    Write-Host "Gathering resource group tags for subscription $($sub.name)"
    $groups = az group list --subscription $sub.id | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        if (
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Email" -in $deletedUsers.value.mail -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.businessPhones -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.displayName -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.givenName -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.id -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.jobTitle -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.mail -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.mobilePhone -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.officeLocation -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.preferredLanguage -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.surname -or
            $group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name" -in $deletedUsers.value.userPrincipalName
        )
        {
            Write-Host "Found group `"$($group.name)`" belonging to `"$($group.tags."Tech-Owner-Name")`" <$($group.tags."Tech-Owner-Email")>"
            $found++
        }
    }
}

if ($found -gt 0)
{
    throw "Found $found groups belonging to people who are no longer with us"
}
```

Note that `$deletedUsers.value` is a list of objects, but `$deletedUsers.value.mail` expands to a list of strings :D

## The pipeline that runs every day

From there, you can use Azure DevOps pipelines to run this script periodically

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

schedules:
- cron: "0 12 * * *"
  displayName: Daily check
  branches:
    include:
    - main

variables:
  - group: deleted-owners-checker

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: az login
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: az login --service-principal -u $Env:applicationId -p $Env:password --tenant $Env:tenantId
  env: 
    applicationId: $(applicationId)
    objectId: $(objectId)
    password: $(password)
    tenantId: $(tenantId)
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: run script
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: scripts/listdeleted.ps1 # our repo has a folder called scripts containing the relevant script, update this based on your own
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: az logout
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: az logout
    condition: always() # log out even if other tasks fail
```

This necessitates having a service principal that can be [logged in during pipeline execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal) and has permissions to read your resource groups and has User.Read (Application) graph [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). The credentials for the service principal can be passed to the pipeline using the Azure DevOps Library [connected to an Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops).

You can alternatively use a [devops ARM service connection in a CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) instead of manually logging in to the CLI, but I've had issues with this in the past so I prefer to manually log in.

## The notification

Note that the scripts exits with an error if any groups belonging to gone-people are found, this lets you use pipeline-failed emails as your notification system. A better method would be [Teams webhooks](https://pakstech.com/blog/azure-devops-teams-message/) in the PowerShell script, but that's farther than I've gotten with this.

## The infrastructure-as-code

I prefer to automate the creation of the service principal and key vault using Terraform.
This should take care of creating the key vault, creating the service principal, giving the service principal `Reader` perms on the resource groups (inherited), and giving the service principal the graph permission needed to query deleted users (might need admin consent).

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.23.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = ">= 2.21.0"
    }
  }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name = "my-rg-where-i-want-my-key-vault-to-go" # change me!
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "main" {}

resource "azuread_application" "main" {
  display_name = "deleted-owners-checker"
  owners = [
    data.azurerm_client_config.main.object_id
  ]
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # microsoft graph

    resource_access {
      # User.Read.All
      id   = "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214"
      type = "Role"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "main" {
  application_id                = azuread_application.main.application_id
  owners                        = azuread_application.main.owners
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "main" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.main.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "main" {
  principal_id = azuread_service_principal.main.object_id
  scope = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/00000000-000000000-000000000-0000000" # management group that contains the resource groups you care about, change me!
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "main" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.main.tenant_id
  location = "canadacentral"
  sku_name = "standard"
  name = "deleted-owners-checker"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "me" {
  secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Purge"]
  certificate_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Create", "Delete", "Import", "Purge"]
  key_permissions         = ["Get", "List", "Create", "Delete", "Import", "Purge"]
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.main.id
  tenant_id               = azurerm_key_vault.main.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.main.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "devops" {
  secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List"]
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.main.id
  tenant_id               = azurerm_key_vault.main.tenant_id
  object_id               = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
  # You would think this would be the object ID of the principal used by the service connection used when connecting the key vault to the Azure DevOps Library
  # In reality, you're better off creating the key vault access policy from the Azure DevOps web interface, since the object ID was different for us when we tried
  # The azure pipeline should let you know if the object ID is wrong. We got a pipeline error like this when we first tried. The error should give you the correct object ID to use
# objectId: "The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=5555-55555-5555-5555;iss=https://sts.windows.net/zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'deleted-owners-checker;location=canadacentral'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287. The specified Azure service connection needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected key vault. To set these permissions, download the ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and execute it, or set them from the Azure portal."
# applicationId: "The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=5555-55555-5555-5555;iss=https://sts.windows.net/zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'deleted-owners-checker;location=canadacentral'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287. The specified Azure service connection needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected key vault. To set these permissions, download the ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and execute it, or set them from the Azure portal."
# tenantId: "The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=5555-55555-5555-5555;iss=https://sts.windows.net/zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'deleted-owners-checker;location=canadacentral'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287. The specified Azure service connection needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected key vault. To set these permissions, download the ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and execute it, or set them from the Azure portal."
# password: "The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=5555-55555-5555-5555;iss=https://sts.windows.net/zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'deleted-owners-checker;location=canadacentral'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287. The specified Azure service connection needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected key vault. To set these permissions, download the ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and execute it, or set them from the Azure portal."

}

locals {
  kv_secrets = {
    objectId = azuread_application.main.object_id
    tenantId = azuread_service_principal.main.application_tenant_id
    applicationId = azuread_service_principal.main.application_id
    password = azuread_application_password.main.value
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "main" {
  for_each = local.kv_secrets
  name = each.key
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.main.id
  value = each.value
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.me
  ]
}
```